# Conformal parametrization of an ellipse

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I am looking to a formula for the conformal map from the unit disc in the interior of an ellipse centered in $0$ and with semiaxes $a,b>0$. I know that depends on elliptic function, but I didn't find any references.

Thanks in advance for any formula or reference.

Answer (score 6):

[The paper](https://www.mas.ucy.ac.cy/english/technical2007/TR-27-2007.pdf) *Conformal mapping for the efficient MFS solution of Dirichlet boundary value problems* by Andreas Karageorghis and Yiorgos-Sokratis Smyrlis (Computing, May 2008, Volume 83, Issue 1, pp 1-24) seems to provide the formula you desire (section 2.2), as well as more references apropos of its derivation.

#### Supplementary references

[The paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/AASF/Vol31/kanas.pdf) *On conformal representations of the interior of an ellipse* by Kanas & Sugawa seems to meander around your question. In the first section they remark that Schwarz found such a map back in the day, but so far I have been unable to locate it a source for it. Section 3 discusses an ODE which one of your desired functions satisfies.

[The paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2005-133-09/S0002-9939-05-07817-2/S0002-9939-05-07817-2.pdf) *Ellipses, near ellipses, and harmonic Möbius transformations* by  Martin Chuaqui, Peter Duren and Brad Osgood  (Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 133 (2005), 2705-2710)  deals with mapping the boundaries of the domains you're considering. While it is not immediately useful, it may be of interest. At the end, the authors remark that a conformal map of the form you desire will ''not be able to map concentric circles to concentric ellipses''.

Comment: It looks the reference I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I found a better one! It's in the new edit.

Comment: The second and third link are broken.

Comment: @MartinR The second link works for me, but I've updated the third.

Comment: It seems that my Safari browser doesn't like it if the link does not start with `https`. Do you mind if I change that?