# Show that $|f'(0)|\le\max \{\frac{a}{b^2},\frac{b}{a^2}\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ and $$E=\left\{w=u+iv\in\mathbb{C}:\frac{ u^2}{a^2}+\frac{v^2}{b^2}<1\right\}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers. Let $f:E\to D$ be holomorphic. Show that $$|f'(0)|\le\max \left\{\frac{a}{b^2},\frac{b}{a^2}\right\}$$
 You may use without proof the fact that the critical points of 
$$\rho(t)=\frac{(a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t)^{1/2}}{a^2\cos^2t+b^2\sin^2t}$$ are exactly the zeros of $\sin(2t)$

**My thought**:

If $0<r<1$ is close to $1$ then $\gamma(t)=ra\cos t+irb\sin t$ lies in $E$ and close to $\partial E$.

Maybe we can use Schwarz's lemma since we want to bound $|f'(0)|$? Then by Riemann Mapping theorem I can map the region $E$ to a unit disc. Then how to determine the form of the map?

Is this the right direction to solve this problem? Also what does zeros of $\sin 2t$ has to do here?

Could anyone kindly help? Thank you!

Comment: Your regon $E$ is an ellipse. This might be relevant http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207934/conformal-parametrization-of-an-ellipse

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: The boundary of $E$ can be parameterized by $z(t) = a\cos t + ib\sin t$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

By Cauchy's Integral formula, we have:

$|f'(0)|$ $= \left|\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int_{\partial E}\dfrac{f(z)}{z^2}\,dz\right|$ $= \left|\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{f(z(t))}{z(t)^2}z'(t)\,dt\right|$ $\le  \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{|f(z(t))|}{|z(t)|^2}|z'(t)|\,dt$

$\le \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}(a^2\sin^2t + b^2\cos^2t)^{1/2}\,dt$ $= \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\rho(t)\,dt$.

Can you bound the last integral using the fact about $\rho(t)$ given in the problem?